# Trying to implement a comments system with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

Trying to implement a comments system using pusher on my laravel project. Everything seems to be in order, however every post request which is meant to send the input data to the database returns with error 500.
Used F12 on firefox to monitor what gets sent to /tip/select, it seems that it passes the text of the comment just fine, so it could be the issue with the controller.

Routes
    `Route::get('/tip/select','TipController@select');
Route::post('/tip/select', 'TipController@addComment');`

Comment model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Zttp\Zttp;
use App\model\User;
use App\Tip;

class Comment extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];

protected $table='comments';
//protected $fillable=['tip_id','user_id','body'];
public static function moderate($comment)
       {
           $response = Zttp::withoutVerifying()->post("https://commentator.now.sh", [
               'comment' => $comment,
               'limit' => -3,
           ])->json();
           if ($response['commentate']) {
               abort(400, "Comment not allowed");
           }
       }
public function tip(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Tip');
}
public function user(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\model\User');
}
}
```

Controller

```
use Pusher\Laravel\Facades\Pusher;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Input;
use DB;
use Image;
use App\Tip;
use App\model\User;
use App\Subcategories;
use App\Category;
use App\City;
use App\Comment;
use App\CityAreas;
//use App\Http\Requests\TipFormRequest;

class TipController extends Controller
{
 public function select(){
     //$db=DB::table('tips')->orderBy('created_at','desc');
     $data=Tip::get();

     $url = Storage::disk('s3');
     //$data=Tip::paginate(10);
     //$data=$db->get();
     // dd($data);
     $comments = Comment::orderBy('id')->get();
     return view('tip', compact('data', 'url','comments'));
}

/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/

 public function create(){
   $categories=Category::all();
   $cities=City::all();
   return view('tip.create',compact('categories','cities'));
 }

 /**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/

 public function store(Request $request, City $city, Category $category){
   $this->validate($request, [
     'image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999']);
   $tipsnew = new Tip;
   $tipsnew->title = $request->title;
   $tipsnew->description = $request->description;
   $tipsnew->category_id = $request->category;
   $tipsnew->city_id = $request->city;
   $tipsnew->user_id = auth()->id();
   $tipsnew->url = $request->url;

  if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
     try{

       $file = $request->file('image');
       $name = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $img = \Image::make($file->getRealPath());
       $img->fit(1080);
       $img->stream();
       Storage::disk('s3')->put('tip'.'/'.$name, $img->__toString());
       $tipsnew->image = 'tip'.'/'.$name;
     }
     catch (\Exception $e)
               {
                   $response = [
                       'information' => 'Error. Something went wrong. Please try again',
                   ];
                   $statusCode = 400;
                   return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
             }
       }
   $tipsnew->save();



   return redirect ('tip/create')->with('status','your tip is created');
 }

 public function edit($id){
   $tip=Tip::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
   $categories=Category::all();
   $selectedCategories=$tip->categories->lists('id')->toArray();
   return view('tip.edit',compact('tip','categories','selectedCategories'));
 }

 public function search(Request $request, City $city, Category $category, User $user){
     $q = $request->get('q');
     if ($q != ""){
      $tips = Tip::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                 ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                 ->orWhereHas('user', function($id) use($q){
                   return $id->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
                 })
                 ->orWhereHas('city', function($id) use($q){
                   return $id->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
                 })
                 ->orWhereHas('category', function($id) use($q){
                   return $id->where('name', 'LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
                 })
                 ->get();
              if(count($tips) > 0)
        return view('tip.search', ['tips' => $tips]);
     }
 }

 public function addComment(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request;
        Comment::moderate($data['text']);
        $comment = Comment::create($data);
        Pusher::trigger('comments', 'new-comment', $comment, request()->header('X-Socket-Id'));
        //add creation of new comment to DB
        $commentnew = new Comment;
        $commentnew->user_id = Auth::user()->id();
        //$commentnew->tip_id= $request->post(['tip_id']);
        $commentnew->body = $request->text;
        $commentnew->save();
        return $comment;
    }
}
```

Snippet of the blade

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<form onsubmit="addComment(event);">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Add a comment" name="text" id="text" required>
                      <input type="hidden" name="tip_id" id="tip_id" value="{{$val->tip_id}}">
                      <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
                      <button id="addCommentBtn">Comment</button>
                  </form>
                  <div class="alert" id="alert" style="display: none;"></div>
                  <br>
                  <div id="comments">
                      @foreach($comments as $comment)
                          <div>
                              <small>{{ $comment->username }}</small>
                              <br>
                              {{ $comment->text }}
                          </div>
                      @endforeach
                  </div>
                  <!--jQuery script used to be here -->
                  <script>
                  function displayComment(data) {
                   let $comment = $('<div>').text(data['text']).prepend($('<small>').html(data['username'] + "<br>"));
                   $('#comments').prepend($comment);
                  }
                  function addComment(event) {
                   function showAlert(message) {
                       let $alert = $('#alert');
                       $alert.text(message).show();
                       setTimeout(() => $alert.hide(), 4000);
                   }
                   event.preventDefault();
                   $('#addCommentBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                   var data = {
                       text: $('#text').val(),
                       username: $('#username').val(),
                       tipid: $('#tip_id').val(),
                   };
                   fetch('/tip/select', {
                       body: JSON.stringify(data),
                       credentials: 'same-origin',
                       headers: {
                           'content-type': 'application/json',
                           'x-csrf-token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                           'x-socket-id': window.socketId
                       },
                       method: 'POST',
                       mode: 'cors',
                   }).then(response => {
                       $('#addCommentBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                       displayComment(data);
                       showAlert('Comment posted!');
                   })
                  }
                  </script>
```

Comment: Check the logs in `storage/logs`, the details of the 500 would be there.

Comment: Don't have logs folder in storage, but thanks for a tip

Comment: Have you checked the web server logs, usually found in `/var/log/<apache|httpd|nginx>`?

Comment: @aynber I have my setup on a windows machine, where would I need to look for those?

Comment: It depends on which web server you're using. Check the documentation or settings for the location of the error logs.